# Wait for future to end before printing a variable

Tags: scala

In this code I need to print variable `seq`, but since it's printed before the futures are processed it is printed empty. How to wait for variable `seq` to be populated before the statement `println(seq)` is executed?

```
object TestFutures5 extends App {

  def future (i:Int) = Future { i * 10 }
  val seq = Seq[Int]()

  for ( x <- 1 to 10 ) {
    val future2 = future(x) 
    future2.map {  y =>
       println(y)
       seq :+ y
    }
  }

  println(seq)  // <-- this always prints List()

  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statement must be executed after all the futures completed, which means that you need to store a reference to each created future. Your sequence is also immutable so you can not add elements to it. If you want to do this in without mutating variables your loop should be refactored like this:

```
  val futureResult = (1 to 10).map {
    x =>
       future(x)
  }
```

Then simply use `Future.sequence` to group the futures and do the print:

```
Future.sequence(futureResult).map(res => println(res))
```

Comment: this is the output I get: `20
10
50
30
70
80
100
40
90
60
List()`

Comment: I expected `println(seq)` to print the entire sequence, instead it prints an empty list (note that the first 10 numbers are printed by `println(y)`

Comment: @ps0604 the problem is that your list is not mutable. You are never changing the value of `seq` and you would need a mutable list in order to do so. See my updated answer.